# Handle MediaPlayer exceptions from throwing infinite errors

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've implemented a service for MediaPlayer so that I can continue playing even after minimizing the app. The problem is whenever the MediaPlayer fails to play a song (e.g. The file not exists or the MediaPlayer source path is wrong) it throws an common error,

```
Error (-38,0) start called in state 0
```

This one keeps running in an infinite loop and since its in a background service so it's difficult to prevent this occurance. In this scenario I want to force close the MediaPlayer and wait till MediaPlayer starts playing another song.

I've already tried,

```
if (mp! = null && mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.release();
}
```

But this doesn't stops the MediaPlayer throwing errors after getting an exception. I would like to know what would be the best practice to prevent such exception. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the error using `onErrorListener` on your MediaPlayer, like

```
mp.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // handle your error here like exit media player or show message
         or move to next song

        return true;
    }
});
```

Here, the main thing is to `return true`, if you `return false` then error will not be handled by you.

Comment: I'll take that answer. Returning "true" from the OnErrorListener() did the trick. Thanks a bunch.